# Microeconomics Min Operator Derivative?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, economics

A perfection complements model has a utility of $U\left(x,y\right)=min\left\{3x,y\right\}$.

I'm struggling to calculate the marginal utility of x and y (which is the partial derivative of x or y) when y>3x or when y<3x.

I do know that when:

y>3x

$MUx=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=3$

$MUy=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$

y<3x

$MUx=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$

$MUy=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=1$

I'm not sure how to mathematically generate these results. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you don't how to get $MUx=3$, for instance?

Comment: Exactly. In my single variable and integral classes, we never integrated a function where we had a min operator. I'm only used to more traditional functions.

Answer (score 1):

I write down all $4$ cases:

**1**. For $y>3x$ we have $U=\min\{3x,y\}=3x$. That means for the two partial
derivatives:

\begin{eqnarray*}
& a. \qquad \qquad  \frac{\partial U}{\partial x }\left.\right\vert_{y>3x}=3 \\ \\
& b.\qquad \qquad  \frac{\partial U}{\partial y }\left.\right\vert_{y>3x}=0
\end{eqnarray*}

**2**. For $y<3x$ we have $U=\min\{3x,y\}=y$. That means for the two partial
derivatives:

\begin{eqnarray*}
& a. \qquad \qquad  \frac{\partial U}{\partial x }\left.\right\vert_{y<3x}=0 \\ \\
& b.\qquad \qquad  \frac{\partial U}{\partial y }\left.\right\vert_{y<3x}=1
\end{eqnarray*}

If you comprehend the resulting function of two case decisions then it is straightforward  to get the partial derivatives.

Comment: Right, yes, ok. Thank you so much!

Comment: @findingmyway You´re welcome. Feel free to accept the answer. Thanks in advance.